# Patching together weak solutions of SDE's at random time points

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

Suppose we are given a sequence of drift coefficients $b^n : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ and we know that the following SDE has a weak solution, unique in law on $[0,\infty)$

$$dX_t^n(\mu) = b^n(X_t^n(\mu))\,dt + \,dW_t, X_0^n(\mu) \sim \mu$$

Suppose further we are given a sequence of hitting times $\tau_n(\mu) = \inf\{ t\geq 0 : X_t^n(\mu) \in A_n\}$ for some sequence of closed sets $(A_n)_n$.

I want to patch the $X^n$ together at the hitting time into a single process $X$, like so:

Fix an initial distribution $\mu_0$. We consider the solution $X^0(\mu_0)$ until $\tau_0$. Then continue with $X^1(\mu_1)$ until $\tau_1$, where $\mu_1 = \operatorname{Law}(X^0_{\tau_0}(\mu_0))$, etc.

For every $n$ we have a weak solution $(\Omega_n, \mathcal F_n, \mathbb P_n, (\mathcal F_t^n)_{t\geq 0}, W^n, X^n)$ (modulo a time shift). Then, how can we define the process $X$ on a single filtered probability space, such that the filtration satisfies the usual conditions and we we are dealing with a single Brownian motion?

Intuitively we could take a product of the spaces, but I'm struggling to see how to patch together the filtrations, since they need to be patched together at random times.

Comment: do you think we can use strong Markov property here since you want to use the same Brownian motion. So we hit $A_{0}$ with $X^{0}$ at some time $\tau_{0}$. Then of course by SMP $Y^{0}_{t}=X^{0}_{t+\tau_{0}}$ is a new process. So here I am thinking of taking the germ-filtration generated by that process $Y_{t}$ for all $t>0$ i.e. $$F_{\tau_{0}}:=\sigma(\bigcap_{t>0} Y_{t} )$$.

Comment: And then using that to patch the filtrations, which I think that means $$F_{t}:=F_{(0,\tau_{0})}\cup F_{\tau_{0}}\cup F_{(\tau_{0},t)}$$
where  $F_{(\tau_{0},\tau_{0}+t)}=\sigma(X^{1}_{t}(\mu_{1}))$. This patching I think allows for Markov property for the entire patched process.